# android button fatal exception

Tags: android, button

My button gives fatal exception and stops. I checked the internet and cannot find any solution. When i delete inside the function there is no problem what is wrong inside the function.
Can anybody help me about it. I am compiling it on android 4.4.2

Here is my function inside the MainActivity

```
public void btnRegister(View v) {
Intent i = new Intent ( this, Register.class );
startActivity(i);
}
```

Here is the XML code

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:src="@drawable/register"
android:onClick="btnRegister"  />
```

Comment: problem could be you have not declared the activity is manifest. or the problem could be Resgister activity

Comment: change `this` in `Intent` to `YourActivity.this` and post your logcat

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan that is not an issue if `this` refers to Activity Context

Comment: just replace this with "YourActivityName.this" in your button method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declared your button as:

```
 Button btnRegister= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
 btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then change your

```
public void btnRegister(View v) {
Intent i = new Intent ( this, Register.class );
startActivity(i);
}
```

to this one:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {   
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class);
startActivity(i);
}}
```

and make sure you have declared your Register activity in your Manifest:

```
<activity
android:name=".Register"
android:label="@string/your_layout">
</activity>
```

Comment: No need to initialize button and i believe `this` refers to activity context

Comment: Actually from explanation above is not really understandable. Maybe he needs to mention how he is calling the intent.

Answer (score 0):

just replace your this code

```
 public void btnRegister(View v) {
 Intent i = new Intent ( this, Register.class );
 startActivity(i);
 }
```

with

```
public void btnRegister(View v) {
   Intent i = new Intent ( YourActivityName.this, Register.class );
startActivity(i);
}
```